# UPDATE Column in SQL to be equal to the number of rows in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this Select that counts the number of `localName` in the table Local where `indIP` is equal to `indIP` in the table Segment and grouped by `segmentName`

```
SELECT COUNT(localName) FROM Local L, Segment S WHERE L.indIP = S.indIP  GROUP BY segmentName;

COUNT(localName)

 - 2
 - 1
 - 3
```

And now I wanna put this number in the column `nbRooms` in the table Segment to the right row with an Update looking like so :

```
UPDATE Segment SET nbRooms = ***
```

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM Segment

indIP | segmentName | nbRooms

 - 3---------first ----------------2
 - 4---------second------------1
 - 5---------third----------------3
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Segment s
    SET s.nbRooms = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Local l WHERE l.indIP = s.indIP);
```